# Product Custom Option "File Upload" not working

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, file-upload

Have strange issue with uploading files at fronted with the custom option "file" of a product:

When I specify the file upload as a required field I always get a
`Please specify the product required option(s)`
as a message

- `Magento 1.9.1`
- Permissons to media folder are set to 777
- file upload in the backend works fine
- fiddler says: `HTTP 200 /ajax/index/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL20xOS5iYW5uZXJ0ZXVmZWwubmV0L2ZhaG5lbnN0b2ZmLWJhbm5lci1oaXNzZmxhZ2dlLXRleHRpbGJhbm5lci1mYWhuZW5tYXN0/product/46/form_key/FDumHtEmtk7w6ZuU/` HTTP/1.1
- according to fiddler there's no http POST (or PUT) for the file upload.. it themes that he doesn't even try

all other custom options work fine - clicking the "add to cart" button makes a POST to an URL like `/ajax/index/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL20xOS5iY` - which adds the item to the cart.

I checked other posts before but non of the solutions helped.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

And I figured that was theme problem. I've tried the default Magento's theme and worked fine, on my custom theme.

In my case I had to disable the `ajax's` add to cart and it worked.

So it must be some conflict with `jquery`, `ajax` of your custom theme.

Comment: Did you find a way to have ajax enabled and still use file upload in the end?